# How reinstall application after changes in androidManifest without removing previous version of application

Tags: android

How reinstall application after changes in android.manifest without removing previous version of application?

I have ready installed application on phone. Then I changed something in AndroidManifest.xml and build apk file. Now I want install application on phone,
but I get "The application has not been installed."

When I remove old version and then install new everything is ok, but another device I want reinstall app without removing previous version, because I don't want lost data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="eu.treative.fca_pops">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:minSdkVersion="30"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Fcapops"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

`The application has not been installed.`

Sometimes that error not because of the android manifest.

Make sure that the apk had signed by the same certificate.

That case sometimes happens to me, when I install the release version from google play, then I install debug version from my local project.

After making sure that the apps signed by the same certificate, make sure that the app had the same or bigger number build version.

You can't replace apk with build versionCode 12 with build versionCode 11, should be 12 or higher.

Comment: Where Can I set build number?

Comment: Check this article.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element

Comment: version code is build number, should be an integer, and should be incremental from the previous version of your app.
the version name is a string. that would be appearing at the app info, seems like v.0.0.1-beta

Comment: Version code is in app/build.gradle, you can increase the version number but can not decrease it.